# Obtener valores de un array

Tags: php, array

Tengo este arreglo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no puedo acceder a sus valores ya intente con un foreach etc.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código en vez de la imagen, es más sencillo reproducir el ejemplo, gracias.

Comment: ¿podrías dejar algún ejemplo del código?

Answer (score 1):

Si conoces los indices del array, puedes acceder a ellos asi:

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    Array(
        "curp" => "VELE94",
        "cve_incr" => 299,
        "cve_pais" => 9
    )
);

foreach($array as $i => $val) {
    echo $val['curp'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Según el array mostrado para acceder a estos valores, podrías utilizar esto:

```
<?php 
$array = array ( 0 => array ("curp" => "valor", "etc..." => "valor 2") );
foreach ($array[0] as $llave => $valor) {
  echo "$llave = $valor \n"; 
} 
?>
```